# Post JSON product data from Angular to Rails LineItem controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a calculator (to calculate some counts of product and additional positions), written on AngularJS, I am using gem "angular-rails-resources".

I want to pass data from calculator to LineItem (for cart) controller in rails.

```
    productCenter.factory('LineItem', ['railsResourceFactory', function       (railsResourceFactory) {
    return railsResourceFactory({
        url: '/line_items',
        name: 'line_item'
       });
     }]);


    LineItem.query().then(function (results) {
        $scope.line_items = results;
    });


    $scope.addLineItem = function() {
     new LineItem ({
        product_id: $scope.selectedProduct.id,
      # whole_count: $scope.wholeCount,
     }).create()
    }
```

In rails i have "create" method from Agile Web book:

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
end
```

In rails routes:

```
post "line_items/:product_id" => "line_items#create"
```

And when I click on "Add to cart" button, in console i have error:

```
Started POST "/line_items" for ::1 at 2015-12-05 02:45:35 +0300
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"line_item"=>{"product_id"=>2}, :product_id=>{}}
  Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 27]]
  Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'={}):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:41:in `create'
```

If I change find params in "create" method in LineItem controller this way:

```
def create
    product = Product.find(product_params)
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
 private
   def product_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
   end
end
```

In console I have next error:

```
Started POST "/line_items" for ::1 at 2015-12-05 02:46:22 +0300
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"line_item"=>{"product_id"=>2}, :product_id=>{}}
  Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 27]]
  Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'={"product_id"=>2}):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:41:in `create'
```

In short:
I need to pass many calculated information in angular like: count, consumables_count, instruments_count. And this is why I am using angular and json. But:

1. I can not find product by id in rails LineItem controller (product = Product.find(product_params) - ERROR)
2. And I don't know how to pass calculated information to the rails
   controller, and how to handle it, that I could view this calculated
   information in cart? (e.g. @cart.line_items.whole_count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
product = Product.find(product_params)
```

You pass `{"product_id" => 2}` as parameter for `find`. This is not correct, instead you should do like this:

```
product = Product.find(product_params[:product_id])
```

`find` accepts only identifier of a record in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I code this way:

```
def create
    product = Product.find(product_params[:product_id])
    product_attr = product_attr_params
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id, product_attr)
   end 

private
 def product_attr_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:whole_count, :trim_count, :tools_count, :consumables_count, :fill_count, :finish_count, :install_count)
    end 

    def product_params
        params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
    end
end
```

Product_params and product_attr_params => should be merge

My POST from AngularJS

```
      new LineItem ({
            product_id: $scope.selectedProduct.id,
            whole_count: whole_count,
            trim_count: trim_count,
            tools_count: tools_count,
            consumables_count: consumables_count,
            fill_count: fill_count,
            finish_count: finish_count,
            install_count: install_count,
        }).create()
```

And LineItem model:

```
def add_product(product_id, attr)
        current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
        if current_item
            current_item
        else
            current_item = line_items.build(
                product_id: product_id,
                whole_count: attr[:whole_count],
                trim_count: attr[:trim_count],
                tools_count: attr[:tools_count],
                consumables_count: attr[:consumables_count],
                fill_count: attr[:fill_count],
                finish_count: attr[:finish_count],
                install_count: attr[:install_count],
                )
        end
        current_item
    end
```